# Relative Path in Other Java Class

Tags: java, path, relative-path

How are you?

I'm working into a Java Project and my IDE is Eclipse. What's going on is that I have a Constants.java to set some paths to get into other classes, but Eclipse can't locate the file I have to find.

The code line here is on Constants.java to get a spreadsheet that is in dataDriver inside my project.

```
public static final String File_Path = "../../../../../../dataDriver/DataFile.xlsx";
```

Anybody could help me getting this file?

Comment: For resources included within the project (somewhere in the class path) consider this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java).  Also, if _dataDriver_ is a package name, then follow standard naming conventions and change the name to _datadriver_.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in your project then use this:

```
public static final String File_Path = "./dataDriver/DataFile.xlsx";
```

'.' is used for current directory and '..' is used for parent directory.

Comment: Actually I have 6 levels of folders to write something on Constants.java, so i thinks that's correct...

Comment: 6 levels of folder is your package, I think ?